# In angular how to get system language settings (en-GB)

Tags: angular

In my application, I need to get the system language settings value (e.g) en-GB / hi-IN / en-US.
I'm able to get browser setting value. But in my case I need system setting value.

I'm new to Angular. Is there any package available? Please advice.

I want to get my system setting lang **not browser setting lang**

navigator.systemLanguage - In Angular it is not supported

Thanks

Comment: in a component you can inject in constructor LOCALE_ID:`constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale,...){}`. ng serve give the value of this variable when you create the application using ng build --localize (or when you use i18n) , but you can force this value if you use in your module a provider: `providers:[{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'es-ES'}, ...]`. Sorry, It's hard explain in a comment, check the docs [about Internatization](https://angular.dev/guide/i18n)

Comment: Thanks for the support @Eliseo. I'm using`@Inject(LOCALE_ID) protected localeId: string` and passing `this.localeId` as you mentioned. By defult the value is passed as en-US (my browser setting value). But my regional system setting value is en-GB. I want to get the system setting value. Also I canot hardcode the value `useValue: 'es-ES'`